# Актуализация информации

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, веб-программирование, клиент-сервер

Есть Клиент, который работает с WCF службой.

WCF служба в свою очередь предоставляет информацию из MS SQL БД.

Клиент может менять данные через WCF службу на SQL сервере.

Собственно вопрос, как правильно поддерживать данные на клиенте в актуальном состоянии?

На сколько верным решением будет каждые 5 минут по таймеру запрашивать у WCF службы данные? Может быть есть более грамотный подход?

Comment: зависит от бизнес требований. безопаснее всего при каждом запросе доставать данные из базы.

Comment: вместо объявления награды лучше бы было уточнить вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было ответить

Comment: см. о duplex channels [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx), [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx) а также [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF), [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service), [здесь](https://mikesdotnet.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/broadcasting-messages-using-a-duplex-wcf-service/) и т.п.

Answer (score 8):

[SQL Server может уведомлять WCF службу об](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787891.aspx) изменениях в интересующих её таблицах. А служба, в свою очередь, [уведомлять клиентов-подписчиков](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22796/WCF-Implementation-of-the-Publisher-Subscriber-Mod).

Answer (score 1):

По молодости была такая ошибка, при старте программы закачивал много данных с БД, потом написал обёртки к коллекциям, которые эти множества синхронизировали. При старте программа долго грузилась и было много ещё каких косяков. 
Согласен с @AdamSkywalker всё зависит от бизнес требований.

Есть альтернативный подход.
Загружать данные под конкретную операцию, к примеру нужно найти договор, не нужно загружать все 100500 договоров. А потом скролить и искать нужный договор. Это неправильно с точки зрения UX. Пользователь все равно в один момент времени не видит 100500 договоров. Загрузить 10 последних договоров и показать их пользователю. Он не нашел, ввел критерии поиска (фильтр + сортировка) и под этот фильтр запрашивается обозримое пользователем количество договоров, после того как он выбрал договор, всё это список не нужен, он выбрасывается из памяти.

Comment: При чем здесь "скрол" и вообще GUI?

Comment: @Igor с точки зрения синхронизации не при чем. Описал ситуацию как можно избежать синхронизации.